# Classes provided via Gradle project compile dependency won't be found

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

System configuration:

- Java 10.0.1
- Gradle 4.8

It worked already with this project configuration:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(":core")
}
```

Suddenly it has stopped working and I've got compile errors related to classes and packages in the project the current one depends on.

```
error: package core.utils does not exist
```

The dependency tree looks good, too:

```
|
+--- project :core
|    +--- ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade to Gradle 4.8.1 solved the issue.